# Bootstrap: possible to use .dl-horizontal as a mixin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I'm trying to style one of my definition lists horizontally, without hardcoding `class="dl-horizontal"` into my HTML. This was my attempt:

`.some-section dl {
   .dl-horizontal;
}`

However, that doesn't work. Do I have the syntax wrong or am I just trying to achieve something that will not be that easy?

Comment: Assuming you have the bootstrap loaded, that should do it. All it is going to add is some code for a media query ([see where it is defined in bootstrap as of this writing](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e25dacba149e23490da0028954be4ec3c1ded8a3/less/type.less#L204)).

Comment: Hm, the most recent official version (3.1.1) looks like this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/type.less#L198. There's a difference and I've just noticed that compilation gives me this warning: *NameError: .dl-horizontal is undefined*. So the problem will probably go away with a new version (I don't really want to use development version). Thanks.